# sequence increasing/bounded question

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I was doing this question, and wasn't too sure about part iv). My working out is below. If anyone could verify if parts i-iii are fine and provide some hint for iv), that would be great.

Given the sequence $a_0 = -3, \; a_{n+1} = \sqrt{{a_{n}^{2}+a_{n}}}, \; n≥0 $.

i) Is {$a_{n}$} from $n=0$ to infinity, increasing?

Ended up proving this was true, pretty confident about my answer

ii) Is {$a_n$} from $n=0$ to infinity, bounded above?

Ended up finding it is not bounded above

iii)Does the limit of $a_n$ as n approaches infinity exist?

The limit of $a_n$ as $n$ approaches infinity does not exist as the sequence is not bounded

iv) Suppose that we change the recurrence to $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{{ca_{n}^{2}+a_{n}}}$,  for some constant c. Can you choose a (nonzero) value of c so that you get a different limiting behaviour
compared to the answer in iii)?

By pure intuition, I've went with no, however I'm not entirely sure about this one.

Comment: If you don't insist on $a_0=-3$ then $c=\frac 2 3$ works. Here  $a_n=3$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can play around with numerical simulations in Excel to look at what's happening and give you intuition.  Plugging in $c=.5$ makes an apparent stabilization at $2$,   $c=.4$ appears to stabilize at $\frac 5 3$,  and $c=.3$ is of course undefined because $.3*(-3)(-3)+(-3)<0$

This last one though provides a nice simple key...where's the break point to get 0?  $c=\frac 1 3$.
Plug that in, and you get $a_n=0$ for all $n\geq 1$, which is a pretty simple limiting behavior to prove :)

For extra credit, try to prove if the other values make it converge,  and what values of $c$ are the break point between convergence and divergence.